# UIButton image not animating inside UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uibutton, uiviewanimation, autolayout

My primary goal is to create an expand/collapse tableview with few custom properties. My logic and configurations are as follows:

1. I am using AutoLayout on a UITableViewCell and in it I added a UIButton with an image of an arrow. I use a UIButton here because the image is a template image which I need to be tinted without writing a single line of code and UIImageView does not work at tinting the image unless done by code.
2. On the `[tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath]`  of the tableView delegate, I have written my logic to open(insert rows) and/or collapse (delete rows).
3. The expand and collapse functions call a method on the custom UITableViewCell with the button inside it to animate the arrow using the code below:

   ```
   [UIView beginAnimations:@"rotateDisclosure" context:NULL]; 
   [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
   self.buttonArrow.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2); 
   [UIView commitAnimations];
   ```

The problem I'm having is that the animation is not working.

However I call it from `[tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath]` the animation works.

I tried adding after the button transformation code inside the animation block the following without success:

1. `[myCell setNeedsDisplay];`
2. `[myCell setNeedsLayout];
   [myCell layoutIfNeeded];`

If you know what I'm doing wrong or what is really happening and how I can make the above work, please describe.

Thanks!

Comment: You are using a really old method for animation. You should be using the block based methods on UIView instead.

Comment: Can you make sure that the code in your cell is called from didSelectRowAtIndexPath by setting a breakpoint? I've tried the animation code and it works, that doesn't seem to be the problem.

Comment: @Abizern I don't think the problem lies with me using the old method. I used the block based method and it gives the same result.

Comment: @pallzoltan yes the didSelectRowAtIndexPath is being called.

Answer (score 0):

Following @pallzoltan answer, I have tried it in a separate project my self and figured out that I am using a wrong method to retrieve the cell in question. Instead of using `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, I was dequeuing the cell at that indexPath.

I have not provided much of that information in my question above which is why most have not pinpointed the issue.